# Trouble with quaternions in a sprite and script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I'm making a 2-d platforming shooter game in Unity5 using some Asset store pre-written scripts and some online tutorials that I'm throwing together to get my desired effect, however i'm having an issue with a script that just won't work 100%, and I believe it's due to my lack of experience with both c# and quaternions.

I'm a Graphic designer and not a Game dev or programmer by any means, but i'd say i'm at a hobbyist level of c#, i can understand what i see and bodge some basic code but this has me stumped. I'm making a 2d side-scrolling game with a sprite that runs and jumps, with a weapon that follows the mouse on-screen. The effect I'm looking for is for the sprite to flip when the mouse postion exceeds what would be it's North and South on the X axis, or essentially have his body sprite facing the same direction as the mouse.

https://github.com/MattWinfield/GameCode <------ Here is the Github link to both the full scripts in use.

```
public class PlatformerCharacter2D : MonoBehaviour 
{
        Transform playerGraphics;
        private static float ArmDegree;

        private void Awake()
        {
            playerGraphics = transform.Find("Body");
        }

        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            ArmDegree = armRotation.rotationZ;

            if (ArmDegree > 90 || ArmDegree > -90 && m_FacingRight)
            {
                Flip();
            }
            else if (ArmDegree < 90 || ArmDegree < -90 && !m_FacingRight)
            {
                Flip();
            }
        }

    private void Flip()
    {
        m_FacingRight = !m_FacingRight;

        // Multiply the player's x local scale by -1.
        Vector3 theScale = playerGraphics.localScale;
        theScale.x *= -1;
        playerGraphics.localScale = theScale;
    }
}
```

```
public class armRotation : MonoBehaviour
    {

    public static float rotationZ;
    public int rotationOffset;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 difference = 
    Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
        difference.Normalize();

        rotationZ = Mathf.Atan2 (difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotationZ + 
    rotationOffset);

    }
}
```

I want the body sprite, referenced as playerGraphics in the code to flip on the x axis whenever the rotation of the arm exceeds the x axis, so that the sprite is facing he same side as the position of the mouse pointer, but with the hassle I'm having with the quaternions, the sprite flips in strange points and i cant seem to get it to work.

Comment: Do you have any gif that shows the sprite not flipping correctly? Comment a link down here I ll edit your post

Comment: Are you using a `SpriteRenderer`?

Comment: Maybe this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/55741520/7111561

Comment: `if (ArmDegree > 90 || ArmDegree > -90 && m_FacingRight)` soo.... `if (ArmDegree > -90 && m_FacingRight)`? And the same goes for the else statement too.

Comment: Thanks @Draco18s , Thinking about it in that way definitely helped, i wasn't thinking straight when i wrote the `m_FacingRight` boolean in the if parameters. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

So i suppose i was tired or just needed to think about it a bit longer, i got it working, the code is clunky and inefficient but it works and i can streamline later.

```
        if (ArmDegree < 90 && ArmDegree > 0 && !m_FacingRight)
            {
                Flip();
                m_FacingRight = true;
            }

        else if (ArmDegree > 90 && ArmDegree <180 && m_FacingRight)
            {
                Flip();
                m_FacingRight = false;
            }
        else if (ArmDegree < 0 && ArmDegree > -90 && !m_FacingRight)
            {
                Flip();
                m_FacingRight = true;
            }
        else if (ArmDegree >-180  && ArmDegree < -90 && m_FacingRight)
            {
                Flip();
                m_FacingRight = false;
            }
```

I basically just took the characters x and y and split it to quadrants, doubling the code but halving the headache it took to wrap my head around it. But thanks for your help guys.